# Django complex query based on dicts

Tags: python, sql, django

**Tldr of Problem**

Frontend is a form that requires a complex lookup with ranges and stuff across several models, given in a dict. Best way to do it?

**Explanation**

From the view, I receive a dict of the following form (After being processed by something else):

```
{'h_index': {"min": 10,"max":20},
   'rank' : "supreme_overlord",
'total_citations': {"min": 10,"max":400},
'year_began': {"min": 2000},
'year_end': {"max": 3000},
}
```

The keys are column names from **different** models (Right now, 2 separate models, Researcher and ResearchMetrics), and the values are the range / exact value that I want to query.

**Example (Above)**

Belonging to model `Researcher` :

- rank
- year_began
- year_end

Belonging to model `ResearchMetrics`

- total_citations
- h_index

`Researcher` has a One to Many relationship with `ResearchMetrics`
`Researcher` has a Many to Many relationship with `Journals` (not mentioned in question)

Ideally: I want to show the researchers who fulfill all the criteria above in a list of list format.

`Researcher ID, name, rank, year_began, year_end, total_citations, h_index`

```
[[123, "Thomas", "professor", 2000, 2012, 15, 20],
[ 343 ...                                   ]]
```

What's the best way to go about solving this problem? (Including changes to form, etc?) I'm not very familiar with the whole form query model thing.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are `Researcher` and `ResearchMetrics` related? Can you show us your model definitions?

Comment: @DanielHepper Will update question, They have a one to many relationship

Comment: If this is about learning the basics, then go through at least the intro documentation for Models, Views, Forms and Templates in the Django Documentation. If this is about solving a problem, it's already [been solved](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) for you.

Comment: Definitely about a particular problem, and I did go through the documentation :s Your link throws an error @Melvyn

Comment: Link works fine for me, but here's another: https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-filter/

Comment: Are you sure? the documentation link throws a DNS cannot be found error

Comment: I think my real road block is figuring how to do "between" or "greater than" "less than" queries from a hash, in that format? @Melvyn

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically perform a query you pass a `dict` with items `'fieldname__lookuptype': value` as **kwargs to `Model.objects.filter`.

So to filter for `rank`, `year_began` and `year_end` in your example above, you would do this:

How exactly you do the transformation depends on how variable this incoming dictionary is. An example could be something like this:

```
filter_in = {
    'h_index': {"min": 10,"max":20},
    'rank' : "supreme_overlord",
    'total_citations': {"min": 10,"max":400},
    'year_began': {"min": 2000},
    'year_end': {"max": 3000},
}

LOOKUP_MAPPING = {
    'min': 'gt',
    'max': 'lt'
}

filter_kwargs = {}
for field in RESEARCHER_FIELDS:
    if not field in filter_in:
        continue
    filter = filter_in[field]
    if isinstance(filter, dict):
        for filter_type, value in filter.items():
            lookup_type = LOOKUP_MAPPING[filter_type]
            lookup = '%s__%s' % (field, lookup_type)
            filter_dict[lookup] = value
    else:
        filter_dict[field] = filter
```

This results in a dictionary like this:

```
{
    'rank': 'supreme_overlord',
    'year_began__gt': 2000,
    'year_end__lt': 3000
}
```

Use it like this:

```
qs = Researcher.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Regarding the fields `total_citations` and `h_index` from `ResearchMetrics`, I assume you want to aggregate the values. So in your example above you want either a sum or an average.

The principle is the same:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

METRICS_FIELDS  = ['total_citations', 'h_index']
annotate_kwargs = {}
for field in METRICS_FIELDS:
    if not field in filter_in:
        continue
    annotated_field = '%s_sum' % field
    annotate_kwargs[annotated_field] = Sum('researchmetric__%s' % field)
    filter = filter_in[field]
    if isinstance(filter, dict):
        for filter_type, value in filter.items():
            lookup_type = LOOKUP_MAPPING[filter_type]
            lookup = '%s__%s' % (annotated_field, lookup_type)
            filter_dict[lookup] = value
    else:
        filter_kwargs[field] = filter
```

Now your `filter_kwargs` look like this:

```
{
    'h_index_sum__gt': 10,
    'h_index_sum__lt': 20,
    'rank': 'supreme_overlord',
    'total_citations_sum__gt': 10,
    'total_citations_sum__lt': 400,
    'year_began__gt': 2000,
    'year_end__lt': 3000
}
```

And your `annotate_kwargs` look like this:

```
{
    'h_index_sum': Sum('reasearchmetric__h_index')),
    'total_citations_sum': Sum('reasearchmetric__total_citations'))
}
```

So your final call looks like this:

```
Researcher.objects.annotate(**annotate_kwargs).filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

There are some assumptions in my answer, but I hope you get the general idea.

There is one important point: make sure you properly validate the input to make sure that only the field can be filtered that you want the user to filter. In my approach, this is ensured by hard coding the field names in `RESEARCHER_FIELDS` and `METRICS_FIELDS`.